# How do I sort decimal numbers in ascending order in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview that displays rows of data with prices in each row. I am trying to create a sorting algorithm using DropDownList, such that for instance if I choose the DropDownList value that says "low to high" ,the prices in the gridview display will be sorted from the lowest to the highest.

This is what I have tried so far, but it does not work. I am wondering if I have done it wrongly?

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList.Text == "Low to High")
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("lowToHigh", con);
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        }

    }
}
```

My stored procedure for the sorting:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[lowToHigh]
@price decimal (6,2),
@tourName varchar(MAX),
@image varchar(MAX),
@description varchar(MAX)


AS
BEGIN
SELECT @tourName,@image,@price,@description FROM Tours ORDER BY tourName 
ASC,price ASC;

END
RETURN 0
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are there errors? What happens?

Comment: Why are you selecting input parameters? hope your select statement should be `SELECT tourName,image,price,description FROM Tours ORDER BY tourName ASC,price ASC;`

Comment: You also aren't executing your stored procedure, so nothing will happen.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a whole load of things that are wrong with this code, far too many for us to be very helpful in the long run. I suggest you go and read up on how this should work, run through some tutorials on C#, data access and SQL Server.

Comment: Why are you using stored procedure? can you show gridview data loading query?

Comment: What are you trying to sort? The stored proc doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: I am trying to sort the price (decimal values) displayed in the gridview. I thought by adding "lowToHigh" (name of stored procedure) in my sqlcommand i am executing it? i did this for my other pages and it works, just that i didnt do sorting for those pages. It does not work: when i click on the dropdown list value the data doesnt get sorted. Since you guys know that i did wrongly can someone be kind enough to suggest the correct way to do? @AndyG,Sankar,DavidG,Metehan Senol,Imperial Justinian

Comment: "I thought by adding "lowToHigh" (name of stored procedure) in my sqlcommand i am executing it?". No you're just setting the command to be used later. Take any ADO.NET tutorial, it'll show you what to do. Your procedure itself also looks invalid, you can't put parameters instead of the column names. Have you actually tested the procedure in isolation (i.e. unit-tested it) before trying to connect it to the application?

Comment: P.S. You can also do sorting entirely in the C# / aspx via the gridview's sort expressions, rather than writing a whole new query just to change the order. Again you can read about it and find lots of tutorials online. Always worth studying a topic in detail before you attempt it, very rarely are you the first person to have a similar requirement.